# Windows 2008 Ldap and terminology?

Tags: windows-server-2008, ldap

I have configure a root AD/Ldap server.

For this example, its url is as follows:

```
home.example.com

Users (Other than default):
    + foo
       + Member of: DnsAdmins, Domain Admins, Domain User
    + ldapUser1
    + ldapUser2
```

I have 2 machines that have been authenticated to this network and are using it to login in.

```
Windows 7 
    + localAdmin

Linux (Joined with the help of centerfy express)
    + root
```

I have been able to loginto both machines using `ldapUser1` and `ldapUser2`

No I am configuring a service to utilize this ldap server. However the configuration wants the following:

DN?
OU?
UID?

What would these be in respect the configuration noted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I suggest looking at your directory using a 'plain' LDAP client like `adsiedit.msc`, or [AD Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963907.aspx), or [Apache Directory Studio](http://directory.apache.org/studio/). You will see the "full" structure that the "Users & Computers" tool simplifies.

- In LDAP, an entry consists of attributes, one of which is used as the entry's name ("relative distinguished name", RDN).

  The "Users" folder is identified by the `cn` (common name) attribute, giving `cn=Users`, and an "organizational unit" is identified by the `ou` (organizational unit name) attribute, giving `ou=Sales` or such. Active Directory also uses `cn` for user entries, while some other systems use `uid` (login name).
- An entry's full "distinguished name" (DN) therefore consists of its RDN along with the RDNs of all its parents, so if you have a hierarchy like this...

  ```
  dc=com
  └─ dc=example
     └─ ou=People
        └─ cn=Fred Foobar
  ```

  ...its DN will be `cn=Fred Foobar,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com`.
- "OU" means an organizational unit – frequently just used as a regular folder. If the question is "which OU should user accounts be taken from", the answer would be the base DN of that folder; e.g. `ou=Sales,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com`.
- In the RFC 2307 schema, user objects have an "`uid`" attribute containing the login name. In Active Directory the closest equivalent would be "`sAMAccountName`" (or in some cases "`userPrincipalName`"). Most likely you will have to tell your LDAP client to use the Active Directory attribute set.